# How to visualize karma/jasmine test failures for very large strings or objects?

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am working on an Angular project that can convert certain files to other formats.  In the end I'm just generating very long strings, or very large objects and converting them into strings, and then writing them to a file.

In my Jasmine tests I'm having a lot of trouble with these because it's very difficult to see why a test failed when the strings or objects are so large.  It just says:

> Expected '[very large string]' to equal '[other large string]'

But of course those very large strings run off the page and are sometimes even truncated in the error message.  Even if they weren't it can be difficult to spot small differences, or sometimes even invisible differences like `\n` vs `\r`.

Is there some kind of Jasmine plugin that will show something visual, like a diff, between the expectation and the actual result to make this kind of testing easier?

---

Here's a screenshot example of what I'm dealing with. The only way I've found to debug this is to `console.log` out each string and paste them into a diff viewer.

[image: large string test failure in Jasmine]

---

Right now I am attempting to rule out whitespace characters as the issue with this helper function, but it doesn't seem to be helping me track down the issue.

```
export class TestUtils {
  public static normalizeWhitespace(str: string): string {
    return str.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, '\n').replace(/\n\s+/g, '\n');
  }
}
```

which I use in my expectation

```
expect(TestUtils.normalizeWhitespace(outputContent))
  .toEqual(TestUtils.normalizeWhitespace(expectedString));
```

Comment: It may be not the best, but I would do what you said you are doing. Logging them out and then pasting them in a diff checker.

Comment: I would love a diff viewer right there in the Jasmine output window for when `.toEqual()` or `.toBe()` is called with differing strings or objects.  The current way is really a poor UI/UX way of showing what is different.  As it turns out my issue above was due to timestamps and generated UUID's, which of course will be different (my mistake!) but it took a lot more work to figure that out than should have been needed IMO.